# jQuery UI Autocomplete plug-in pass in optional data for ajax call

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm using [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) plug-in. I'm giving it an URL to make an ajax call and retrieve data. I want to pass optional data parameters but not as part of URL.  In the code they make a [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) call and pass in 'request' parameter(which is an optional data parameter), however I don't see a way to get at this request parameter.

```
this.source = function( request, response ) 
{
    $.getJSON( url, request, response );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
source: function(request, response){
    $.post("/path/to/url", {data:request.term, **extra:parameter**}, function(data){     
        response($.map(data, function(item) {
        return {
            /* handle response */
        }
        }))
    }, "json");
}
```